# Is there any effect on Result due to column ordering in Group by clause in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

If i have 20 `columns` and want to get result based on group by clause. Is there any effect on result if I change the order of `columns` in `SQL` query.

My example is as follows :

```
Select  
R.ClientId
,R.FirmName
,R.StrategyID
,R.SecurityType                 
,SUM(R.QtySent)
,SUM(R.ExecutedQty) AS ExecutedQty
,SUM(R.CrossedExecutedQty) AS CrossedExecutedQty                    
FROM ClientDetail m inner join ClientMaster c on 
    m.clordid = c.masterorderId                     
    and m.msg_id = 43
    and c.msg_id in (10,11,12,40)--Msg_Id 40 for manual trade

inner join #ResultsDaily R on c.clordid = R.clordid
GROUP BY R.TethysClientId 
,R.FirmName
,R.StrategyID
,R.SecurityType
```

Comment: No..u can write columns in any order

Comment: The column order is irrelevant. Important is only the column order in the group by clause.

Comment: @Jithin Shaji please take a look comment of 'niyou'.

Comment: @NeerajDubey, See the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
--Query 1
SELECT  R.ClientId      --A
        ,R.FirmName     --B
        ,R.StrategyID   --C
        ,R.SecurityType --D                 
        ,SUM(R.QtySent)
        ,SUM(R.ExecutedQty) AS ExecutedQty
        ,SUM(R.CrossedExecutedQty) AS CrossedExecutedQty                    
FROM    ClientDetail m 
JOIN    ClientMaster c 
        ON      m.clordid = c.masterorderId                     
        AND     m.msg_id = 43
        AND     c.msg_id in (10,11,12,40) 
JOIN    #ResultsDaily R on c.clordid = R.clordid

GROUP BY R.TethysClientId   --1
        ,R.FirmName         --2
        ,R.StrategyID       --3
        ,R.SecurityType     --4
```

In the above Query, 1,2,3 and 4 can be of any order. same time A,B,C and D can be also be in any order.

No column should be missed , thats all.

Parden, if i misinterpreted the Question.